How to handle the back button and touch out side event of DialogFragment?
I have a dialogFragment with a cancelButton, my cancelButton needs to run some logics on press, and then it will dismiss the dialog.
By default, pressing on backbutton and the outside area of the DialogFragment also dismisses the dialog, how do I handle all these events and make then run the same logics as my cancel button?
I cannot simply handle onDismiss because I also have a confirm button where I run a different set of logics and then dismiss the dialog.
